# How to make an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

I am confused as to how to make an array of structs. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct line
{
   int x;
} *line;

int main()
{
    line *array = malloc(10 * sizeof(line));

    int i = 0;

    for(i; i < 2; i++)
    {

        array[i]->x = 5;
    }

    for(i; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]->x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My confusion comes from the following: From my understanding if you have a typedef and give it a name to a pointer eg *line then you can access and mutate each item in the struct using the -> symbol. I don't seem to be getting it right and not sure why.

My error:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You `typedef` `line` as a pointer to the struct, not the struct itself. So when you `malloc`-ed based on the `sizeof line`, you got space for ten pointers, not ten copies of the struct. Remove the `*` before `line` in the `typedef`, so you get an array of structs, not an array of (unallocated) pointers to struct. You'd then use normal dot access after indexing the pointer.

If you actually want an array of pointers to struct, you'd need to allocate each of the structs individually, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here, fixed it for ya:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct line
{
   int x;
} Line;

int main()
{
    Line* array = malloc(10 * sizeof(line));

    int i = 0;

    for(i; i < 2; i++)
    {

        array[i].x = 5;
    }

    for(i; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i].x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer without the colloquialism of the first sentence, and with an explanation of what you changed and why it matters.  The `for (i; i < 2; i++)` notation is not good either, though it is copied from the question — especially for the second loop which invokes undefined behaviour since it is accessing uninitialized data.  If you're not going to do anything in the initialization part, leave it empty, but it would be better to always use `for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)` or even (C99 or later) `for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)` and drop the definition of `i` outside of the loops.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler was index variable  `i` the same reason for the downvote on my answer as well?  Other than mentioning that or possibly giving a more detailed answer I don't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it, you just need to adjust either your syntax or allocate more memory for each struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct line
{
   int x;
} *line;

int main()
{
    line *array = malloc(10 * sizeof(line));

    int i = 0;

    for(i; i < 2; i++)
    {
        // XXX HERE YOU ALLOCATE MORE MEMORY
        array[i] = malloc(sizeof array[i]);
        array[i]->x = 5;
    }
    // XXX RESET "i" TO ZERO
    for(i=0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]->x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You also never reset the `i` array index variable before using it again.